# How to match days for current and previous months sequentially in Oracle SQL?( e.g. 1-jun as monday is matched with 4th jun of monday)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Lets consider jun and may month,
1st jun is Monday then I will check for first Monday in may month and it is on 4th may.
Like that I want to matched all others days sequentially.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood the question:

- `curmon` CTE creates current month
- `prevmon` CTE creates previous month
- in a final query (line #13 onward), the *key* is the `NEXT_DAY` function

---

```
SQL> with
  2  curmon as
  3    (select trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + level - 1 as datum
  4     from dual
  5     connect by level <= last_day(sysdate) - trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + 1
  6    ),
  7  prevmon as
  8    (select trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'mm') + level - 1 as datum
  9     from dual
 10     connect by level <= last_day(add_months(sysdate, -1)) -
 11                         trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'mm') + 1
 12    )
 13  select to_char(c.datum, 'dd.mm.yyyy, dy') cdatum,
 14         --
 15         to_char(next_day(p.datum, to_char(c.datum, 'dy')), 'dd.mm.yyyy, dy') result
 16  from curmon c join prevmon p on to_char(c.datum, 'dd') = to_char(p.datum, 'dd')
 17  order by c.datum;

CDATUM          RESULT
--------------- ---------------
01.06.2020, mon 04.05.2020, mon
02.06.2020, tue 05.05.2020, tue
03.06.2020, wed 06.05.2020, wed
04.06.2020, thu 07.05.2020, thu
05.06.2020, fri 08.05.2020, fri
06.06.2020, sat 09.05.2020, sat
07.06.2020, sun 10.05.2020, sun
08.06.2020, mon 11.05.2020, mon
09.06.2020, tue 12.05.2020, tue
10.06.2020, wed 13.05.2020, wed
11.06.2020, thu 14.05.2020, thu
12.06.2020, fri 15.05.2020, fri
13.06.2020, sat 16.05.2020, sat
14.06.2020, sun 17.05.2020, sun
15.06.2020, mon 18.05.2020, mon
16.06.2020, tue 19.05.2020, tue
17.06.2020, wed 20.05.2020, wed
18.06.2020, thu 21.05.2020, thu
19.06.2020, fri 22.05.2020, fri
20.06.2020, sat 23.05.2020, sat
21.06.2020, sun 24.05.2020, sun
22.06.2020, mon 25.05.2020, mon
23.06.2020, tue 26.05.2020, tue
24.06.2020, wed 27.05.2020, wed
25.06.2020, thu 28.05.2020, thu
26.06.2020, fri 29.05.2020, fri
27.06.2020, sat 30.05.2020, sat
28.06.2020, sun 31.05.2020, sun
29.06.2020, mon 01.06.2020, mon
30.06.2020, tue 02.06.2020, tue

30 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

As of error you reported ("invalid column aliasing"), it is that your database version (what is it? 10g?) doesn't support this:

```
with curmon (datum) as         --> "datum" here is what Oracle complains about
  (select sysdate from dual)
```

but you have to write it as

```
with curmon as
  (select sysdate as datum from dual)        --> alias moved here
```

Comment: when I am trying to execute this query on plsql developer there is an error occur an  "ORA-32033: unsupported column aliasing". Please help me to resolve this problem

Comment: I edited my answer and explained what was wrong. Have a look, please.